# SpringCloudStream - Failing on spring-core version

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I started playing with Spring Cloud Stream/App Starters using spring boot. When I followed the instruction on Getting Started, I am getting the following error with mvn build:

```
An invalid artifact was detected.

This artifact might be in your project's POM, or it might have been included transitively during the resolution process. Here is the information we do have for this artifact:

    o GroupID:     org.springframework
    o ArtifactID:  spring-core
    o Version:     <<< MISSING >>>
    o Type:        jar
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-stream-sample-app</artifactId>
    <version>01.00.00.01-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-cloud-stream.version>1.0.3.RELEASE</spring-cloud-stream.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>stream.Application</start-class>
        <spring-boot.version>1.4.0.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>exec</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Properties file

```
logging.level.org.springframework.integration=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.integration.handler.advice=TRACE
logging.file=/logs/SpringBoot/stream-app.log
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input=start
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output=testchannel
spring.rabbitmq.addresses=localhost:5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
```

your help is appreciated.

Thanks
Karthik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this an issue that you encounter via command-line build or in Eclipse? What Maven version are you using.

Try using the Maven wrapper (`mvnw`) supplied by the `start.spring.io` project.

Cheers,
Marius

Comment: Thanks for your help, I cleaned it up with old versions of Maven and it worked.